# How to proper way of using Diff utils when updating view in adapter kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-diffutils

Hey I am new in **DiffUtil** in adpater. I read some articles from stack overflow, google docs and some articles. I am trying to understand **callback** of **DiffUtil** **areItemsTheSame** and **areContentsTheSame** but, I am not clear what that means. I am adding some code, please have a look. If I am doing wrong please guide me.

**GroupKey**

```
data class GroupKey(
    val type: EnumType,
    val sender: Sender? = null,
    val close: String? = null
)
```

**EnumType**

```
enum class EnumType {
    A,
    B
}
```

**Sender**

```
data class Sender(
    val company: RoleType? = null,
    val id: String? = null
)
```

**RoleType**

```
data class RoleType(
    val name : String?= null
    val id: String? = null
)
```

**Group**

```
data class Group(
    val key: GroupKey,
    val value: MutableList<Item?>
)
```

I am passing my list to adapter which is a **Group** mutableList

```
var messageGroupList: MutableList<Group>? = null
..
val adapter = MainAdapter()
binding.recylerview.adapter = adapter
adapter.submitList(groupList)
```

Using **DiffUtil** in adapter

**MainAdapter.kt**

```
class MainAdapter :ListAdapter<Group, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(COMPARATOR) {

    companion object {
        private val COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Group>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Group, newItem: Group): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Group, newItem: Group): Boolean {
                return ((oldItem.value == newItem.value) && (oldItem.key == newItem.key))
            }
        }
    }
.....
}
```

**1.** Here do I need to compare **key** other property like **type, sender etc.** also inside this DiffUtil.ItemCallback.

**2.** when to use **==** or **===** and what about **equals()**

**3.** If we compare **int**, **boolean** or **String** we use **==** or something else ?

Inside this adapter I am calling another Recyclerview with passing list of **Item** inside that adapter.

**Item**

```
data class Item(
    val text: String? = null,
    var isRead: Boolean? = null,
    val sender: Sender? = null,
    val id: Int? = null
)
```

**NestedRecyclerView.kt**

```
class NestedRecyclerView : ListAdapter<Item, IncomingMessagesViewHolder>(COMPARATOR) {

    companion object {
        private val COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
                return oldItem.id == newItem.id
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
                return ((oldItem.isRead == oldItem.isRead) &&
                        (oldItem.sender == newItem.sender) &&
                        (oldItem.text == oldItem.text))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again Same question Do I need to compare **sender's** other property here as well.

**4.** In **areItemsTheSame** do I need to compare **id** or just **oldItem == newItem** this?

**5.** How to proper way to update my adapter items. In normal reyclerview we use **notifiyDataSetChanged**. But in diffutil do I need to call again **submitList** function and it will take care of everything?

```
adapter.submitList(groupList)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Questions 1 and 4:**

`areItemsTheSame` means that the two instances represent the same data item, even if some of the contents might be different. Suppose you had a list of contacts, and Jane's middle initial has been changed, but the row should still represent the same person Jane. There might be distinct instances of your model class, with some different values, but they are supposed to represent the same row.

So, usually you will compare only one thing between the old and new items that will be the same for each of them in this case. Usually, if you're getting data from a database or API, there will be some unique ID that represents a data point, and that's all you need to compare in `areItemsTheSame`. For example, `oldItem.id == newItem.id`.

`areContentsTheSame` means that if the two instances were each displayed in your list, they would look identical. So if you are using a `data class`, it is sufficient to use `oldItem == newItem` because a data class has an `equals` function that compares every property.

In your Item callback code, it looks like your `areItemsTheSame` is correct, but your `areContentsTheSame` is overly complex. Since Item is a data class, you only need to compare the two items directly.

```
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item) = oldItem == newItem
```

In your Group callback code, maybe you can compare the GroupKeys of the old and new items if that is a valid way to determine the items are the same. Since you are using only a direct `==` comparison, when items change partially you might have some visual defects like views disappearing and reappearing instead of simply having some of their text change.

**Question 2**
You should rarely ever have to use `===` in Kotlin. It does not only check if two items are equivalent, but it checks if the two items refer to the exact same instance in memory. It is not appropriate for DiffUtil.ItemCallback at all.

**Question 3**
`==` is the correct way to compare any two objects. In Kotlin, even primitives should be compared this way because they behave like objects.

**Question 5**
With ListAdapter, you should always use `submitList` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged`. `notifyDataSetChanged` would cause a pointless refresh of all the views and defeat the purpose of using ListAdapter and DiffUtil.

Comment: thanks a million again ✌️. Great

Comment: Hey @Tenfour04 I need your help. I am updating the item in adapter it's not working when updating the item in reyclerview. I added the example. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69698722/diffutil-not-working-with-listadpater-when-view-is-updating-android-kotlin)